# how to process a mime email to vcl

Tags: delphi, indy10

I run a small e mail client build with delphi and indy 10.  Some mails i receive have the mime format or html format. With the current code I just copy the bode.lines to a memo.lines

```
MyMailMemo.Lines.AddStrings
(TIdMessage(Msg.Body);
```

How do I copy the content of mime emails?

Comment: what is your real question now?

Comment: I think he means "process" instead of "progress" but I could be mistaken :)

Comment: I edited it to be more Q&A'ish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MIME-encoded emails do not use the `TIdMessage.Body` property.  They use the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` property instead, where textual MIME parts are stored as `TIdText` objects and attachments are stored as `TIdAttachment`-derived objects.  You have to look at the `TIdMessage.ContentType` property to know whether you are working with an HTML email or a MIME email.  Even then, chances are that HTML emails are actually MIME encoded, as they usually include an alternative plain-text MIME part for non-HTML email readers.  You can loop through the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` looking for a `TIdText` object whose `ContentType` is HTML, then copy the `TIdText.Body` content into your TMemo.