# Find body property inside a message part

Tags: delphi, indy10

Trying to evaluate the mail message content I#m using this code which is derived from 
a [RELEATED QUESTION ON EMAIL WITH INDY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671010/evaluate-email-with-indy-10-and-delphi)

```
DisplayMultiPartMixed(aMsg: TIdMessage; aParentIndex, aLastIndex: Integer);
var
Part: TIdMessagePart;
 i: Integer;
begin
 for i := aLastIndex-1 downto aParentIndex+1 do
   begin
   Part := aMsg.MessageParts.Items[i];
   if (Part.ParentPart = aParentIndex) and (Part is TIdText) then
   begin
    if IsHeaderMediaType(Part.ContentType, 'multipart/alternative') then
     begin
     DisplayMultiPartAlternative(aMsg, Part.Index, aLastIndex);
     Exit;
     end;
  if IsHeaderMediaType(Part.ContentType, 'text/html') then
  begin
      DisplayHTML(Part.Body);
    Exit;
  end;
  if IsHeaderMediaType(Part.ContentType, 'text/plain') then
  begin
      DisplayPlainText(Part.Body);
    Exit;
  end;
  aLastIndex := i;
end;
 // nothing supported to display...
end;
end;
```

I could  not find the body (TStrings) property inside a INDY 10 TidMessage , Part subclass

Answer (score 0):

You need to type-cast the `TIdMessagePart` to a `TIdText`, like the `DisplayMultiPartAlternative()` procedure does.  That omission was just a typo on my part, I fixed it in my answer to the other question.