# Adding reply text to an HTML email using TIdMessage

Tags: email, delphi, indy

I had previously asked a question here. [replace-cidimage-refrences-in-email-body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55823732) The question came about because I am writing a basic email archiver/ archived email viewer.

I had saved the body using

```
IdMessage.Body.SaveToFile(FileName);
```

With the CID references in that body replaced with base64-encoded images, the resulting HTML displays in a `TWebBrowser` component when loaded from a blob field in my database. So I have an email viewer now.

The next requirement is to allow a reply to this email. I've added a `TEdit` above the TWebBrowser, where the UI user can type their single line reply, and I'm using some code to patch the html body to insert the reply line

```
Reply := '<p class=MsoPlainText>';
Reply := Reply + edReply.Text + '<br>';
Reply := Reply + '<br>-----Previous Message-----<br><br>';
Reply := Reply + '</p>';
```

before the first `<p class=MsoPlainText` in that body. This email, sent via IdSMTP, looks good, but Outlook isn't interested in displaying those inline base64-endoded images at all. I need to go back to where I started with this!

I would much like to do something like this:

When the original message is received, save it entirely using this

```
IdMessage.SaveToFile(FBasePath + 'raw_' + MessageID + '.html'); // works, and can be read by M$ Word
```

Then formulate that into a reply

```
IdMessage.LoadFrom(FBasePath + 'raw_' + MessageID + '.html');
IdMessage.Recipients.EmailAddresses := IdMessage.From.Address;
IdMessage.From.Address := repliersaddress;
```

But now the question is, how do I add the reply text to this html email.

```
IdMessage.InsertReply(edReply.Text); // would be great
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no ready made solution for this. You will have to manually extract the base64 images and put them into individual `TIdAttachment...` objects inserted into the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` in the appropriate positions, and update the HTML to replace the images with `cid` references to those attachments, and at your result text as needed. Refer to the [HTML Messages](https://www.indyproject.org/2005/08/17/html-messages/) blog article on Indy's website to help you setup the `MessageParts` layout

Comment: @RemyLebeau Let me get this straight. Starting with the raw_<messageid.>html, I still have to completely disassemble the email into parts and reassemble it, starting with the reply. This sounds horrendous and will entail a significant coding feat given that many of the incoming emails have a hierarchical structure. Or have I hopefully missed something?

Comment: if you have the original email, then no, you simply load it and append the reply text to the `TIdMessage.Body` or appropriate `TIdText` message part as needed, depending on the layout of the email, per the article I linked to. What I described earlier only applies to your mutilated image-extracted emails.